# Что значит переключение контекста с одного потока исполнения на другой?

Tags: java, многопоточность, терминология

Что значит переключение контекста с одного потока исполнения на другой?

Comment: Вы читали [статью на Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0)? Если да, то лучше будет уточнить что именно непонятно.

Answer (score 2):

В статье на [habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/164487/), цитирую:

> Система запоминает состояние (контекст) каждого потока, перед тем как
>   переключиться на другой поток, и восстанавливает его по возвращению к
>   выполнению потока. В контекст потока входят такие параметры, как стек,
>   набор значений регистров процессора, адрес исполняемой команды и
>   прочее…